# where vs after which

Tags: grammar, adverbial-phrases

A native speaker corrected my essay. This is his version. I think "where" clearly modifies the 2012 level because, to modify "during 2015", "after which" would be used. Is my analysis correct?

> The figure once again dropped to **its 2012 level** during 2015,
> **where** it remained until it fell further to an all-time low in 2018 at 3,000.

If I want to modify "in 2015", I should use "after which". Is this correct?

> The figure once again dropped to its 2012 level in 2015, **after which**
> it leveled off for two years until it fell further to an all-time low
> at 3,000.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't modify anything. "Where" is a preposition in the relative clause:  "where it remained until ___", where gap has the noun phrase "its 2012 level" as antecedent. We understand it remained at its 2012 level until it fell further to an all-time low in 2018 at 3,000.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I edited my question before I saw your comments. Could you also comment on my new question "after which"? Is it correct?

Comment: You must understand that it's not the relative word ("where/which/who" etc.) that functions as a modifier, but the whole relative clause. In your original example, it's the whole relative clause _where it remained until it fell further to an all-time low in 2018 at 3,000_ that modifies "its 2000 level". In your new example, the relative pronoun "which" has "2015" as antecedent. The relative clause _after which it leveled off for two years until it fell further to an all-time low at 3,000_  modifies "2015".

Comment: Thank you very much.